# How to get latest date from now on a given date using carbon in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want the nearest date passed  from given date using carbon

```
$givenDate = "2020-07-18";
```

Today is = 2020-12-01

So the result should be the 18th last month. `$result = "2020-11-18"`

Answer (score 0):

you can use subMonth() from now to get the last month then create a new datetime with suitable values:

```
 $givenDate =Carbon::parse( "2020-12-20");
        if($givenDate>Carbon::now())
            $result=Carbon::create(Carbon::now()->year,Carbon::now()->month,$givenDate->day)
                ->format('yy-m-d');
            else
        $result=Carbon::create(Carbon::now()->year,Carbon::now()->subMonth()->month,$givenDate->day)
        ->format('yy-m-d');
```

Comment: Thanks you.  but how about  today date is = 2020-12-20  The result should be 2020-12-18.   not last month

Comment: Now I understand you, I have updated my answer